# mysql: combine date time columns and compare with now

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a column of type date, and another of type time, and I want to select all items that are before now. I can't get it to work. Something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE CONCAT(date_field,' ',time_field)<=NOW()
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Why not store both data in the same column, as `datetime` or `timestamp` data types?

Comment: These are legacy tables with other dependent code and I don't want to make changes to the tables themselves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use MySQL's [`ADDTIME()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_addtime) function:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE ADDTIME(date_field, time_field) <= NOW()
```